# NHibernate query exception, any body help me?

Tags: nhibernate

I have meeting a problem, the code look like simple, but exception:

```
        DDS.Model.ATest atest = new DDS.Model.ATest();
        atest.AID = Guid.NewGuid();

        ISession session = SessionProvider.GetNewSession();
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(atest);

            int count = session.CreateQuery("from ATest").List().Count;
            //Above row throw a exception:
            //Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load items before saving. Commit the transaction first, and then execute the query.

```
DDS.Model.ATest atest = new DDS.Model.ATest();
//atest.AID = Guid.NewGuid(); // You should not assign IDs by yourself

ISession session = SessionProvider.GetNewSession();
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.SaveOrUpdate(atest);
    transaction.Commit();
}

int count = session.CreateQuery("from ATest").List().Count;
```

But that doesn't seem to be the problem in your case. I believe you have ID mapped as Guid or Guid.comb. You should not assign the value to ID. NHibernate will take care of that.

When you assign the value and call session.SaveOrUpdate(), it will try to do update since ID value is not `Guid.Empty`. The update method will fail with the exception: *Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1*, since `UPDATE ... WHERE AID = <some guid>` will be executed.

Comment: But my program logic MUST query before transaction commit, what other method can do?

Comment: Try just removing the AID assignment line. That was causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: ATest.nhb.xml file maped the ID column like this :<id name="AID" type="Guid" unsaved-value="null">
   <column name="AID" length="16" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" unique="true" index="PK_ATest"/>
  </id>

Comment: `SaveOrUpdate` is looking for `id` value to determine if Save or Update operation should be performed. If you set `id` to `Guid.NewGuid()`, and call `SaveOrUpdate`, an update will be performed, since `id` is not equal to `unsaved-value`.

Comment: I changed the code session.SaveOrUpdate to session.Save, no exception, but count=0, and my expect value is 1.

Comment: Have you tried doing it like I wrote above? Also, your `<id>` declaration is missing `<generator>`. The save operation is really dependent on id generator type (whether it's guid, guid.comb, assigned...) and `unsaved-value` attribute.

Comment: BTW, I am not declare <generator> for <id>, since I want use <id> value before the data commit.

Comment: According to the documentation, the generator specification is necessary. For you case, with no arguments to the generator, you can use generator="assigned" as an attribute on the id-element itself.